# Create CentOS 7 local Repo

Tags: centos7, yum

Im using reposync to clone the currnt CentOS7 base repo, and pushing it to an AWS S3 bucket.

I can get this working... but im having trouble getting the latest packages. If I take a fresh CentOS 7 server, and carry out a `yum update` I can see as an example it tries to update bash to `4.2.46-33.el7`, but when i carry out a reposync, I can see that the latest package is `4.2.46-31.el7`, so when I try to complete a `yum update` it says no updates are required.

My command to download the repo locally first is as follows:

`reposync --gpgcheck -l -n -t --r  base -p /s3/centos7/base/ --downloadcomps --download-metadata`

i have tried changing `-n` to `--newest-only` with no luck.

What is a reposync doing differently to the standard yum update for the release version? As the example package is only available in the current 7.7.1908/ folder within the live CentOS repo and not in the 7/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be only poor timing. CentOS have now confirmed the new release, it appears the reposync and the yum update were pulling from different mirrors, one mirror has committed the new release and the other hadn't